# getJSON callback won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

I'm pretty knew to creating JSON objects and passing them on to the browser. For some reason, I'm not getting the callback to work.There is nothing on the console.

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('ajax.cfm?id='+$(this).val()+'&callback=?',null,function(data){
        console.log('here');
    });
});
```

The call is being made, and it is returning a 200 status and the JSON object:

```
configuratorsObj({ 
    "Results" : 8,   
    "items" : [

        {
            vchrName: "Name1",
            itemID: 1782
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name2",
            itemID: 1769
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name3",
            itemID: 1756
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name4",
            itemID: 404
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name5",
            itemID: 248
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name6",
            itemID: 1743
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name7",
            itemID: 5786
        }, 
        {
            vchrName: "Name8",
            itemID: 469
        } 
]})
```

But the call back won't work, even with just a simple console.log('here'). There are no errors on the console.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the data object -- your second parameter -- should be a plain object and is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the url. Try this:

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    var url = 'ajax.cfm?callback=?';
    var data = { id: $(this).val() };
    $.getJSON(url, data, function(data){
        console.log('here');
    });
});
```